# CSV UTF-8 vs Normal CSV in Excel

Tags: excel, csv, utf-8

we have a CSV file that was creating validation errors in a process we run. The validation error made no sense as the error indicated didn't appear as the file was created exactly as instructed. I've tried several ways to resolve it without success. I eventually tried re-saving the file as CSV via Excel and noticed the file was in CSV UTF-8 format and this apparently resolved the error. I noticed the new file size is 3 bytes less than the old one but the content should be exactly the same. The file is completely in English so I am not sure what was causing this. Can anyone advise why the file size is 3 bytes less when saving as CSV rather than CSV UTF-8 format even though data in the file should be identical? These extra 3 bytes likely have caused the validation error.

Thanks for your help

Comment: those 3 bytes are maybe: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Comment: great, that makes sense - thanks for that!